# Video blob data is not posting using xhr

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using rtcmulticonnection.js. I want to save the video on server. Here are two files "index.html" and "save.php". 
`request.open("POST", url);` does not post the data
here the source file link
"https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/v2.2.2/demos/audio-video-screen-sharing-recording.html"

index.html

```
document.getElementById('recordAudioVideo').onclick = function() {
    var localVideoStream = rmc.streams.selectFirst({
        video: true,
        local: true
    });
    if (!localVideoStream) return;
    var recordingSession = {
        audio: true,
        video: true
    };
    var button = this;
    if (button.innerHTML == 'Record Audio/Video') {
        button.innerHTML = 'Stop Recording Audio/Video';
        // http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/startRecording/
        localVideoStream.startRecording(recordingSession);
    } else if (button.innerHTML == 'Stop Recording Audio/Video') {
        // http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/stopRecording/
        localVideoStream.stopRecording(function(blob) {
            //alert('Audio blob size in bytes: ' + blob.audio.size);
            //alert('Video blob size in bytes: ' + blob.video.size);
            var fileType = 'video'; // or "audio"
var fileName = 'ABCDEF.webm';  // or "wav"

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(fileType + '-filename', fileName);
formData.append(fileType + '-blob', blob);
console.log(formData);
xhr('save.php', formData, function (fName) {
    window.open(location.href + fName);
});

function xhr(url, data, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            callback(location.href + request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open("POST", url);
    request.send(data);
}
            button.innerHTML = 'Record Audio/Video';
        }, recordingSession);
    }
```

save.php

```
<?php
// Muaz Khan     - www.MuazKhan.com 
// MIT License   - https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/licence/
// Documentation - https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC
foreach(array('video', 'audio') as $type) {
    if (isset($_FILES["${type}-blob"])) {

        echo 'uploads/';

        $fileName = $_POST["${type}-filename"];
        $uploadDirectory = './'.$fileName;

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["${type}-blob"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
            echo(" problem moving uploaded file");
        }

        echo($fileName);
    }
}
?>
```

the problem is at

```
request.open("POST", url);
request.send(data);
```

`request.open("POST", url);` does not post the data.it does not call `url(means save.php)`.because i have alert some text to see if save.php is called or not. so it does not show any alertbox on client.how can i solve this problem.Also it shows no error on posting.